# Etherscan Sepolia invalid API key

Tags: etherscan, sepolia

After yesterdays maintenance window I started to see `Invalid API Key` errors returned from the Etherscan Sepolia API endpoint. This API key I'm using was working before yesterdays maintenance, and any new keys created run into the same issue.

```
https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api
   ?module=account
   &action=balance
   &address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae
   &tag=latest
   &apikey=$API_KEY

{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Invalid API Key"}
```

Goerli and Mainnet still work fine.

Comment: maybe get a new one and try again.

Comment: @ZartajAfser

`and any new keys created run into the same issue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed after [Scheduled Maintenance for Web (Testnet)](https://etherscan.freshstatus.io/incident/461829)